# Shell code/command with regex to validate json data file

Tags: json, regex, shell, validation

Looking for a shell command /code to validate json input file (if all characters {{[] are present) using regex. Especially end of the file data is ]} as my file json data ends with those characters.

Found we can do it with awk or sed, but unable to get command working on shell.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using regular expressions is simply not feasible. There are theoretical reasons why you cannot solve this problem with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

To validate a JSON file, use a proper tool/parser: [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

```
#!/bin/bash

jq file.json &>/dev/null || echo >&2 "invalid JSON"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OS is redhat 5.xx . I can't install any new tools for security reasons. jq is not present on the system. Any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install any other tool but if you have php installed you can use php's json parser from command line

```
php -r "if ( json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json')) == null ) { echo 'Invalid Json Data'; } else { echo 'Valid Json File'; } "
```